# Nginx configuration for single page app and nested directories

Tags: nginx

I have a directory/files structure such as:

```
root/
  a/
    utils.js
  b/
    assets/
      styles.css
      app.js
    index.html
```

And I want to configure nginx to serve files from `a` directory directly if exist and have single page app in directory `b` (if file in path exists the it wil be served directly, nd if not the fallback will end up at `index.htm` file.

For example:

- `myapp.com/a/utils.js` will return that file.
- `myapp.com/b/` or `myapp.com/b/foo` will display `index.html`
- `myapp.com/b/assets/style.css` will return directly css file

I tries multiple different configurations and non had worke so far. For exampe the simplest:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /root;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

I also tries something to serve different directories:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /root;
    index index.html;

    location /a {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /b {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

I tried to define different roots as well:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    index index.html;

    location /a {
        root /root/a;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /b {
        root /root/b;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Nginx seems to ignore existing files and ends up returning 404 page at all times. When I try to access soe existing file directly it gets redirected to `/` (root) url regardless.

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of a `try_files` statement is the default action. There can only be one. Many of your examples have two. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

The correct URI for your `index.html` file is `/b/index.html` which is what you need to use for the default action of the `try_files` statement.

This should meet your requirements:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /b/index.html;
}
```

You do not state what should happen with the URI `/a/foo`. In the above case, it would also return `index.html`. If you need it to return a 404 response, you would use:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location /b {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /b/index.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I used the above and nginx still not displaying anything that exists and now it goes into infinite redirect loop when hitting any url.